How to add the parent values to child row in the nifi flow file?
Example:
Flowfile data
branches,name,id,acc,serialNo

parent1,abc,123,1234567788,1

child1,eee,345

child2,rrr,678

parent2,mno,786,97865662762,2

child1,ttt,764

child2,ryy,456

output:
parent1,abc,123,1234567788,1

child1,eee,345,1234567788,1

child2,rrr,678,1234567788,1

parent2,mno,786,97865662762,2

child1,ttt,764,97865662762,2

child2,ryy,456,97865662762,2

I have to add the parent last two columns details to Childs of the same parent like parent1 last column details to child1, child2 rows in the flow file.
Please suggest a possible way to use the processor.
